# wrong output in armstrong number program in c

Tags: c

The output is coming as just 0 and 1.

```
int main()
{
int i, n=0, rem, sum=0, temp;

for(i=0; i<1000; i++) {
  temp = n;

  while(temp>0){
      rem = temp%10;
      sum += rem*rem*rem;
      temp /= 10;
  }

  if (sum == i){
    printf("%d ", i);
  }
  n++;
}
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: You initialize `sum` to 0 only once at the beginning of the program, but you should initialize it to 0 at the start of the `for` loop. By doing a minimum of debugging you could have found out this yourself.

Comment: @Syed, set `sum` to 0, just before the `while`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for each value sum has to be zero that is first correction.and i has to be assigned to variable temp because i value has to be checked if it is armstrong number or not.do the changes it will work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
 {
   int i, rem, sum=0, temp;
   for(i=0; i<1000; i++) 
    {
        temp = i;
        sum=0;
        while(temp>0)
         {
             rem = temp%10;
             sum += rem*rem*rem;
             temp /= 10;
          }

       if (sum == i)
          {
             printf("\n%d ", i);
           }
```

}

Output
0
1
153
370
371
407